# share video to facebook using content provider is not working

Tags: android, facebook

share video to facebook using content provider is not  working
private void sharevideoToFacebook() {

```
    Uri videoFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/VID_20151014-WA0013.mp4")));
    ShareVideo video = new ShareVideo.Builder()
            .setLocalUrl(videoFileUri)
            .build();
    Log.d("videouri",videoFileUri.toString());
    ShareVideoContent content = new ShareVideoContent.Builder()
            .setVideo(video)
            .build();
    Log.d("videouri", content.toString());
    ShareApi.share(content, null);
```

Comment: if you found a solution please share.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the official guide to upload video file on facebook, if not read [Sharing Video on FaceBook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)

```
Uri videoFileUri = ...
ShareVideo = new ShareVideo.Builder()
        .setLocalUrl(videoUrl)
        .build();
ShareVideoContent content = new ShareVideoContent.Builder()
        .setVideo(video)
        .build();
```

Comment: are you sure you have settle every thing in a proper way

Comment: ya ..Zubair can u check and whats th problem

Comment: I worked with share the status and image it works well,for video not working

Comment: im getting both uri and content correcty.. runs with no errors but video is not uploading

Answer (score 0):

Videos must be less than 12MB in size.

Read the "Videos" section of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Comment: @ TharakaNirmana I followed that ...worked fine for status and image fails to upload video im using facebook sdk 4.7

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on my app and I solved it.

If you want to share the video in your app, you must install Facebook app.

Using Webview, you can not share video file.

If you want to still share the video in your app, you can use link share feature.

Best